# Jasmine - Testing links via Webdriver I/O

Tags: webdriver, jasmine

I have been working on a end-to-end test using Webdriver I/O from Jasmine. One specific scenario has been giving me significant challenges.

I have a page with 5 links on it. The number of links actually challenges as the page is dynamic. I want to test the links to see if each links' `title` matches the `title` of the page that it links to. Due to the fact that the links are dynamically generated, I cannot just hard code tests for each link. So, I'm trying the following:

```
it('should match link titles to page titles', function(done) {
  client = webdriverio.remote(settings.capabilities).init()
    .url('http://www.example.com')
    .elements('a').then(function(links) {
      var mappings = [];

      // For every link store the link title and corresponding page title
      var results = [];
      for (var i=0; i<links.value.length; i++) {
        mappings.push({ linkTitle: links.value[0].title, pageTitle: '' });
        results.push(client.click(links.value[i])
          .getTitle().then(function(title, i) {
            mappings[i].pageTitle = title;
          });
        );
      }

      // Once all promises have resolved, compared each link title to each corresponding page title
      Promise.all(results).then(function() {
        for (var i=0; i<mappings.length; i++) {
          var mapping = mappings[i];
          expect(mapping.linkTitle).toBe(mapping.pageTitle);
        }
        done();          
      });                  
    });
  ;
});
```

I'm unable to even confirm if I'm getting the link title properly. I believe there is something I entirely misunderstand. I am not even getting each links `title` property. I'm definately not getting the corresponding page title. I think I'm lost in closure world here. Yet, I'm not sure.

**UPDATE - NOV 24**
I still have not figured this out. However, i believe it has something to do with the fact that Webdriver I/O [uses](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/24e30dc6cb0c2429ac4e8863ef73eb874ef865dd/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js) the Q promise library. I came to this conclusion because the following test works:

```
it('should match link titles to page titles', function(done) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, 1000);
  });

  promise.then(function() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
      promises.push(
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
          }, 500);
        })
      );
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      expect(true).toBe(true)
      done();
    });
});
```

However, the following does ***NOT*** work:

```
it('should match link titles to page titles', function(done) {
  client = webdriverio.remote(settings.capabilities).init()
    .url('http://www.example.com')
    .elements('a').then(function(links) {
      var mappings = [];

      // For every link store the link title and corresponding page title
      var results = [];
      for (var i=0; i<links.value.length; i++) {
        mappings.push({ linkTitle: links.value[0].title, pageTitle: '' });
        results.push(client.click(links.value[i])
          .getTitle().then(function(title, i) {
            mappings[i].pageTitle = title;
          });
        );
      }

      // Once all promises have resolved, compared each link title to each corresponding page title
      Q.all(results).then(function() {
        for (var i=0; i<mappings.length; i++) {
          var mapping = mappings[i];
          expect(mapping.linkTitle).toBe(mapping.pageTitle);
        }
        done();          
      });                  
    })
  ;
});
```

I'm not getting any exceptions. Yet, the code inside of `Q.all` does not seem to get executed. I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the WebdriverIO manual, I feel like there are a few things wrong in your approach:

- `elements('a')` returns WebElement JSON objects (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#WebElement_JSON_Object) NOT WebElements, so there is no `title` property thus `linkTitle` will always be `undefined` - http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html
- Also, because it's a WebElement JSON object you cannot use it as `client.click(..)` input, which expects a selector string not an object - http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html. To click a WebElement JSON Object `client.elementIdClick(ID)` instead which takes the `ELEMENT` property value of the WebElement JSON object.
- When a `client.elementIdClick` is executed, the `client` will navigate to the page, trying to call `client.elementIdClick` in the next for loop cycle with next ID will fail, cause there is no such element as you moved away from the page. It will sound something like `invalid element cache....`.

So, I propose another solution for your task:

- Find all elements as you did using `elements('a')`
- Read `href` and `title` using `client.elementIdAttribute(ID)` for each of the elements and store in an object
- Go through all of the objects, navigate to each of the `href`-s using `client.url('href')`, get the `title` of the page using `.getTitle` and compare it with the `object.title`.

The source I experimented with, not run by Jasmine, but should give an idea:

```
    var client = webdriverio
        .remote(options)
        .init();

    client
        .url('https://www.google.com')
        .elements('a')
        .then(function (elements) {
            var promises = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.value.length; i++) {
                var elementId = elements.value[i].ELEMENT;

                promises.push(
                    client
                        .elementIdAttribute(elementId, 'href')
                        .then(function (attributeRes) {
                            return client
                                .elementIdAttribute(elementId, 'title')
                                .then(function (titleRes) {
                                    return {href: attributeRes.value, title: titleRes.value};
                                });
                        })
                );
            }

            return Q
                .all(promises)
                .then(function (results) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                    var promises = [];
                    results.forEach(function (result) {
                        promises.push(
                            client
                                .url(result.href)
                                .getTitle()
                                .then(function (title) {
                                    console.log('Title of ', result.href, 'is', title, 'but expected', result.title);
                                })
                        );
                    });

                    return Q.all(promises);
                });
        })
        .then(function () {
            client.end();
        });
```

NOTE:

- This fails to solve your problem, when the links trigger navigation with JavaScript event handlers not the `href` attributes.

Comment: what is the Q variable? I'm trying to understand but I don't get it.